# NodeJS in Docker - cannot access node_modules

Tags: docker, jenkins, nodes, node-modules

We have a NodeJS project building with Jenkins inside Docker containers.

The problem is taht after image started - we have an error:

> ```
> transform_1 | > node ./build/server.js
> transform_1 | 
> transform_1 | module.js:472
> transform_1 |     throw err;
> transform_1 |     ^
> transform_1 | 
> transform_1 | Error: Cannot find module './lib/express'
> transform_1 |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
> ```

During build in Jenkins - I check permissions and they are OK:

> ```
> ...
> + ls -l node_modules/express/lib
> total 80
> -rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins 1001 14202 Feb 28 12:18 application.js
> -rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins 1001  1954 Feb 28 12:18 express.js
> drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins 1001  4096 Feb 28 12:18 middleware
> ...
> ```

But from container - there is "*Permission denied*" error:

> ```
> admin@swarm-master-EB25F3D5-0:~$ docker run -ti automation/cms-transform-layer bash
> app@3b86a8e8cc4d:~$ ls -l node_modules/express/
> ls: cannot access node_modules/express/lib: Permission denied
> ls: cannot access node_modules/express/node_modules: Permission denied
> total 124
> -rw-r--r-- 1 app app 99111 Feb 28 12:18 History.md
> -rw-r--r-- 1 app app  1249 Feb 28 12:18 LICENSE
> -rw-r--r-- 1 app app  4541 Feb 28 12:18 Readme.md
> -rw-r--r-- 1 app app   224 Feb 28 12:18 index.js
> d????????? ? ?   ?       ?            ? lib
> d????????? ? ?   ?       ?            ? node_modules
> -rw-r--r-- 1 app app  4939 Feb 28 12:18 package.json
> ```

What the hell is `"d????????? ? ?   ?       ?            ? node_modules"`?

The `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM node:7.5.0

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false app

ENV HOME=/home/app

USER root
COPY . $HOME/
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/*

USER app
WORKDIR $HOME

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:production"]
```

**UPD**

Related entries in `package.json`:

```
...
"contentful": "^3.8.0",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"jsum": "^0.1.1",
...
```

Service definition from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
...
transform:
environment:
  - LOGZ_TOKEN=""
  - LOGZIO_API_KEY=""
  - NPM_TOKEN=""
image: "company/transform-layer:latest"
restart: "always"
ports:
  - "3003:3003"
...
```

This is Jenkins pipeline script:

```
...
def npmBuildTransform(repoUrl='1', env='2') {
    docker.image('node').inside('-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock') {
        git branch: "${BRANCH}", credentialsId: 'github', url: "${repoUrl}"
        stage('Transform build') {
           sh 'apt-get update && apt-get -y install rsync'
           sh 'npm config set //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN'
           sh 'npm install --production=false'
           ...
```

Comment: "Solved": made everything under `root` + `permfix` in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: can you also include your package.json scripts, and your docker-compose.yml file? Is this Jenkins Pipeline?

Comment: @PatrickScott Thanks, Patric. Updated. I'm sure it's something wrong with users on CI server during Docker-build and who owns /`jenkins` directory - `jenkins` user with id 1001, and user on dev-server, who owns docker-compose's containers (`serveradmin` with UID 1000). But during build - there is `chown -R app` step. What's wrong wit exactly Node's modules here?
Please - let me know if you need more info. I'll try to reproduce/roll-back to error tomorrow, while we haven't a lot of builds yet.

Comment: what I do, is have jenkins agents that have docker and docker-compose installed. Then I use Jenkins Pipeline set up with github orgs, so each service can define a `Jenkinsfile` and it will be picked up by Jenkins. 

In the Jenkinsfile, I simply call a series of `docker-compose` functions to run tests and build the app within a build container, using mounted volumes from the jenkins workspace.

Comment: I don't even include npm in my final build.. only node, the code, and production dependencies. I think running npm scripts to start production is not a good pattern for docker.

Answer (score 0):

The solution.

I moved all Node's build logic from Jenkin's scripts to the Dockerfile, as suggested by [Patric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237676/patrick-scott) and [some](http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html) resources.

So, the final result is - call Docker build from the Jenkins:

```
        ...
        def appimage = docker.build("projectname/${imgName}:${TAG}", "--build-arg NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN} .")

            appimage.push()
            appimage.push('latest')
        ...
```

And then I do NPM build from the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:7.5.0

ARG NPM_TOKEN="${NPM_TOKEN}"

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false app

ENV HOME=/home/app

USER app
COPY package.json $HOME/

WORKDIR $HOME
RUN pwd && ls -l

RUN npm config set //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}

RUN npm install --production=false
COPY . $HOME

USER root
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME/

USER app
RUN npm run build:production

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:production"]
```

It's kind of "dev" version, few redundant steps/layers like `RUN pwd && ls -l`, but this works.